# Update XMLType adding new attribute to the node

Tags: xml, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

We're stuck in the middle of migrating from Oracle 10 to Oracle 12c.
We have migrated part of the DB which most of data contains XmlType documents. Due to new requirements, some of the documents requires an attribute update.

Initially, we have following xml:

```
<root>
 <a id="1">
  aaaaaaaaaa
 </a>
 <b id="2">
  bbbbbbbbbb
 </b>
</root>
```

After xmlupdate, it needs to be something like this:

```
<root>
 <a id="1">
  aaaaaaaaaa
 </a>
 <b id="2" newAttribute="">
  bbbbbbbbbb
 </b>
</root>
```

In Oracle 10, this would succeed:

```
update TABLE_NAME set whattoUpdate = (select insertchildxml(whattoUpdate, 'xpathexpression', '@attribute', 'valueOfAttribute', 'namespace') as result  from TABLE_NAME where id = XX);
```

This works as it should be, but in Oracle 12 it doesn't work (select statement returns blank xml in `SqlDeveloper`).

According to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/app_depr_upd.htm#ADXDB6046), function `insertchildxml()` is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table example( xml clob);

insert into example values( '<root>
 <a id="1">
  aaaaaaaaaa
 </a>
 <b id="2">
  bbbbbbbbbb
 </b>
</root>');

update example set xml = xmlserialize( document XMLQuery('
xquery version "1.0";
copy $cp := .
modify
    insert node attribute  newAttribute {""} into $cp/root/a
return $cp
'
passing xmltype(xml) returning content) indent size = 2);
```

`xmlserialize(document {xmltype} indent size =2 )` - is changing xml to clob.
`xmluqery` stucture is 
`xmlquery( 'xquery language' passing {xmltype} returning content)`

`copy $cp :=.` create copy of input xml document. Is required because there is no way to modify original data.

`modify
    insert node attribute newAttribute {""} into $cp/root/a
return $cp`- xquery command. Adding new attribute in selected element.